# C - Free a definite Amount of Memory (char**)

Tags: c, arrays, memory, free

I have to safely free an array: `char** a;` It's like a string list. I know how many `char*` I have in it. But I have trouble to release ALL the memory. Is there like a function that I can use like to free 20 bytes ? I tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    if (a[i] != null)
        free(a[i]); // some of a[i] ARE null, non-null have different sizes
free(a); // crashes here
```

but I get runtime errors with `asm` debugging.
Every thing in a has been malloced. For a I malloced 5 strings (each pointer 4 bytes) -> 20 bytes. How can I free the whole `char**` ?

Comment: You might have memory bugs elsewhere. Try using a memory leak detector (like e.g. `valgrind` on Linux)

Comment: What runtime errors? Have they all been `malloc`ed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't free 20 bytes unless you allocated 20 bytes. You can only free a block. The size of that block is specified at allocation time. For each block allocated, you need a separate de-allocation.

You can try to change the size of a block by using `realloc` but that's not deleting an arbitrary part of that block.

If both the array and the indicvidual items in the array have been allocated using `malloc`, then your approach is correct. Free each of the elements, then free the array:

```
char **arr = malloc (10 * sizeof (char*));
if (arr != NULL)
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        arr[i] = malloc (50 + i * 10); // sizes 50, 60, 70, ..., 140

// Use the ten X-character arrays here
//     (other than NULL ones from malloc failures, of course).

if (arr != NULL) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        free (arr[i]);           // Okay to free (NULL), size doesn't matter
    free (arr);
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much how I'm mallocing and freeing. My prog crashes at free(arr); Does it matter if I write to arr[i] with `strncpy` before ?

Comment: Only if you overflow the buffer you allocated for it. It sounds like you have a problem elsewhere which is corrupting the memory arena.

Comment: Thanks! My free-routine was more complicated so I didn't see that I was modifying the arr pointer while freeing the items.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you have properly allocated the char** array and all of the char* arrays that it contains pointer to, the code that you posted should work. What does the rest of your code look like?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code you've posted.
However, you can get a runtime error if you free the same piece of memory twice.
Check the rest of your code and make sure you're actually allocating all the memory in that array, and not freeing it more than once.

Comment: After calling `free`, it is often useful to then set the pointer to NULL.  Then, using a debugger, you can see if the pointer has already been freed.